# How to create an internal search engine only selecting the ingredients of the products?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to create an internal search engine on the web to find the products in the catalog by their ingredients and not by `categories`, `SKU`, `tags`, etc...
I was looking for the option to find how to customize without using a Plugin.

The handicap is that I need to search for products by ingredients that certain products do not contain.

---

> I EDIT the question

---

I had errors in explaining what we are looking for.

The colleague @IvoJerkovic gave the idea that I should do to build the Search Engine, that is why I have searched for information, and perhaps it is not necessary to create a new taxonomy, since the default woocommerce search engine already finds the ingredients that my products have , since they are within the description.
But since I don't know exactly how it works, I can't comment, I can only continue reading information and documentation, and find the correct documentation that does not lead me to confusion.
Is it necessary to create a taxonomy to create this type of search engine?
What I do not understand is how I should create the logic to create the search engine to find the products that do not have the ingredients that I enter in the search bar.
I hope this explains well my intention and what I'm looking for.

I mean, some people are allergic to some products and cannot eat various ingredients, and the serious need is to give them the opportunity to look for products that do not have the ingredients that they are allergic to.
An example, enter the word "sugar" in the search engine, and all products that do not have sugar among their ingredients appear. Indeed someone has already had this idea, and there are examples, but I don't know how to search for them. In the case that I show, the search is filtered by categories and tags.

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<label>
  <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
  <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
</label>

<select id="category_name" name="category_name">
  <option value="">Todas</option>
  <?php $categories = get_categories();
  foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category->slug;?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>

<select id="tag" name="tag">
  <option value="">Todas</option>
  <?php $tags = get_tags();
  foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tag->slug;?>"><?php echo $tag->name;?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>.
```

We could limit the search content, for example, with `post_type.`
.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
```

And then we add a `pre_get_posts` filter:

```
function my_custom_search_query( $query ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
      array(
        'key' => 'prueba',
        'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    ));
  };
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_search_query' );
```

But I don't know which posts I should add, I don't know how to carry out this search of the product description field, I don't know how to make it work, and find products that do not contain the search ingredients.
Everything would be in modifying the select fields, in the search engine. Still, I don't understand what would be the `Query` that I should add in the `values` of the `select`, taking into account that the ingredients are only in the product description. Since WordPress allows you to extend the search to custom fields, this could be done with `meta_query`.

How could I get this?

Should I create an array with the ingredients of all the products?  Any ideas?
Is there an example of something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom taxonomy called "Ingredients" for this. For example:

```
function wcif_register_ingredient_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Ingredients', 'taxonomy general name', 'wcif' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Ingredient', 'taxonomy singular name', 'wcif' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Ingredients', 'wcif' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Ingredients', 'wcif' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Ingredient:', 'wcif' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Ingredient Name', 'wcif' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Ingredients', 'wcif' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'ingredient' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'ingredient', array( 'product' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wcif_register_ingredient_taxonomy' );
```

Then you can use `NOT_IN` operator in WP_Query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ingredient',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'soy', 'milk' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display the product here
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

And if you really prefer using `postmeta` then you can use:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ingredients',
            'value' => 'soy',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'ingredients',
            'value' => 'milk',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But I prefer using custom taxonomy for this as you get the interface, category pages and you can filter by more than one ingridient.

Comment: Your answer is really good @IvoJerkpvic .  I edited the question because I found information. But I don't know if it's really necessary to create a taxonomy, and if so, I don't know how to put your idea into practice, how can I put that into practice? My short experience in php. It may not be necessary to add a taxonomy. WooCommerce already finds the ingredients of the products by default, since they are in the product description. Do you still think that I should create a taxonomy with the ingredients?

Comment: Yes, it will find it if the ingredients are in the description but you wanted to exclude some products based on ingredients. What if I am alergic to soy and milk and want to exclude all products that contain any of them? I would still use the custom taxonomy. My first snippet will create a taxonomy on the product, then you can add ingredients to every product. Second snippet is just an example how can you use the taxonomy in wp_query. Alternatively, there are a lot of plugins that allow you to create your own search form.You can use some of them to create custom search with ingredients filter.